# How would i increment this PyGame line

Tags: python, pygame

I want to increment this pygame line by 59, 11 times. For example, it starts on 59, then 112, than 171 etc. I want the lines to stay shown, so at the end there will be 11 lines all incremented by 59. I can't seem to get it to increment, am i close at all?

```
#Draw lines vertically
for i in range (1, 11, 59):
    pygame.draw.line(window, black, (59, 500 ),(500, 500), 1)
```

Comment: What the heck does it mean to increment a line? Do you want to draw it in a different position?

Comment: It looks like the instruction in your loop doesn't use your 'i' parameter. Is "pygame.draw.line(window, black, (i, 500 ),(500, 500), 1)" any better?

Comment: »59 .. 112 .. 171 ..« what rule creates these numbers?  59 +53 and then +59 again?

Comment: @user2357112 Increment that line. If you don't know what incrementing is, then maybe you shouldn't be commenting on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range (59, 12*59, 59):
    pygame.draw.line(window, black, (i, 500 ),(500, 500), 1)
```

The second parameter for `range` is the stop-value, not the number of iterations. So `range` will only increment once if your increment value is larger than your stop-value.

Comment: Thanks, this worke. But the only problem is it's sitill only displaying on pygame line. How would i get it to display the 11 lines. I see that in the console it's working and incrementing by 59, but their isn't 11 lines :/

Comment: You need to change the coordinates, too. I've edited my answer to what I guess would be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in (1 + i * 59 for i in range(11)):
  pygame.draw.line(window, black, (x, 500 ),(500, 500), 1)
```

Something like this?

Comment: I'll be sure to try it out, thanks ill let you know how it goes